# Facebook sharer shows "error" while my URL contains special characters

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-sharer

Facebook sharer shows "error" while my URL contains special characters for example German special characters "flögeln". That time sharer link created is:

https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=MY_SITE_URL/fl%C3%B6geln

Above URL is not working. While the URL without special characters is working fine, for example:

https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=MY_SITE_URL/abcd

Please suggest how to pass these special character URLs to facebook sharer?

Comment: Did you encode the URL prior to passing it to the sharer?

Comment: Yes. I encoded my url before passing it to "u" parameter of facebook sharer.php. But it does not work. I also tried same without encoding, but does not worked. Please guide.

Comment: Can you share you site URL please

Comment: Its http://80.149.207.74:4899/de123/web/flögeln-flaechennutzung:flaeche-nach-art-der-nutzung which is not wokring. While http://80.149.207.74:4899/de123/web/leonberg-flaechennutzung:flaeche-nach-art-der-nutzung is working. Beucase "flögeln" contains the special characters while "leonberg" does not contains the special characters

Comment: Upon further investigation (using facebook debug object tool), It seems that the url passed to sharer and OG graph URL tag carry different representations of URL. When passed the URL to the debugger it shows it's trying to follow a link inside OG:URL tag which is not accessible. Try un-encoding url in the OG:URL tag

Comment: @RokNemet I have the same issue, but don't have at all any og:url tags in the pages. Look at https://igehiredetes.ma, the links with the text "f megosztás"